# How to highlight all R function names with highlight.js?

Tags: r, regex, syntax-highlighting, highlight.js

I want to extend `highlight.js` capabilities for `R` language so that **(1)** all function names that are followed by opening parenthesis `(` and **(2)** all package names that are followed by `::` and `:::` operators would be highlighted (as it is in RStudio, see Fig.1.). Parentheses `(`, `)` and the operators `::`, `:::` should not be highlighted.

[image: Fig.1. Desired highlighting.]
**Fig.1.** Desired highlighting of `R` code parts (function and package names).

My example consists of two files: `index.html` and `r.min.js`.

HTML file:

```
<html lang="en-us">
<head> <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.12.0/styles/agate.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
</head>

<body>

<pre class="r"><code>doc_name &lt;-
    officer::read_docx() %&gt;% 
    flextable:::body_add_flextable(table_to_save) %&gt;% 
    print(target = &quot;word.docx&quot;)

.libPaths()

c("a", "b")

package::function()$field
</code></pre> 

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highlightjs/cdn-release@9.12.0/build/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script src="r.min.js"></script>
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>

</body>
</html>
```

`r.min.js` file:

```
hljs.registerLanguage("r",function(e){var r="([a-zA-Z]|\\.[a-zA-Z.])[a-zA-Z0-9._]*";return{c:[e.HCM,{b:r,l:r,k:{keyword:"function if in break next repeat else for return switch while try tryCatch stop warning require library attach detach source setMethod setGeneric setGroupGeneric setClass ...",literal:"NULL NA TRUE FALSE T F Inf NaN NA_integer_|10 NA_real_|10 NA_character_|10 NA_complex_|10"},r:0},{cN:"number",b:"0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+[Li]?\\b",r:0},{cN:"number",b:"\\d+(?:[eE][+\\-]?\\d*)?L\\b",r:0},{cN:"number",b:"\\d+\\.(?!\\d)(?:i\\b)?",r:0},{cN:"number",b:"\\d+(?:\\.\\d*)?(?:[eE][+\\-]?\\d*)?i?\\b",r:0},{cN:"number",b:"\\.\\d+(?:[eE][+\\-]?\\d*)?i?\\b",r:0},{b:"`",e:"`",r:0},{cN:"string",c:[e.BE],v:[{b:'"',e:'"'},{b:"'",e:"'"}]},

/* My attempt... */
/* ... to highlight function names between double 
and triple colons and opening parenthesis (in red as symbol): */
{cN:"symbol",b:":::|::",e:"\\(",eB:!0,eE:!0},

/* ... to highlight other function names (in red as symbol): */
{cN:"symbol",  b:"([a-zA-Z]|\.[a-zA-Z.])[a-zA-Z0-9._]*",e:"\\(",eE:!0},

/* ... to highlight package names (in cyan as variable): */
{cN:"variable",b:"(?<!\w)",e:":::|::",eE:!0},

]}});
```

`r.min.js` is based on ([this file](http://cdn.bootcss.com/highlight.js/9.12.0/languages/r.min.js)) and contains `highlight.js` rules to identify `r` code elements.
The lines I added are below the comment "My attempt." Meanings of the abbreviations: `cN` - css class name, `b` - "beggins", `e` - "ends", `eB` - "exclude begin", `eE` - "exclude end", other meanings are explained [here](https://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js/blob/905119aad47d4bb3d4fbaa14df7598034dccb6a3/tools/utility.js).

The result I get (Fig.2.) is not satisfactory. It seems that regular expressions I use do not find the correct beginnings and ends of desired parts of the `R` code.

[image: Fig.2. The result using modified <code>r.min.js</code>]
**Fig.2.** The result using modified `r.min.js`

What should be the correct `highlight.js` code in `r.min.js` to get the parts of `R` code highlighted as in RStudio?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but an alternative approach is to use RMarkdown and get the highlighting done by R, not by `highlight.js`.  The highlighter there uses the R parser, not regular expression matching, so it is guaranteed to match the R language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a worthwhile improvement, so I tinkered for a while with it.

This should be fairly easy,

A regex to capture the package name prefixes could be written like this ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/DjYXsO/1)):

```
\w+(?=:::?)
```

and for function names like this ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/R1hCRo/2/)):

```
\.?\w+(?=\()
```

unfortunately, it is not so easily applied to highlight.js language parsing rules.

After some back and trail and error, I settled with the following code that gives a pretty consistent highlighting:

```js
/* ... to highlight other function names (in orange as a keyword): */
{
    cN: "keyword",
    b: /(^|\s*)(:::?|\.)\w+(?=\(|$)/
},
/* ... to highlight package names (in red as meta): */
{
    cN: "meta",
    b: /(^|\s*)\w+(?=:::?|$)/,
    r: 0
},
```

- I use the cN|className `keyword` for functions this is what it is and it interferes less with the predefined style for functions.
- The same goes for packages names where I suggest to use the cN `meta`. This is what other packages use for similar constructs, and again, it gives a more consistent result for built-in styles, e.g. numbers.
- I've also added `print` and `c` to the list of keywords. The list for the R language is obviously somewhat incomplete. Arguably every function name (even from 3rd party packages) should be added as a keyword - this is how some other languages do it - but that's not very practical).

This is what I [get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSgt3.png).

Sample Code:

```js
hljs.registerLanguage("r",function(e){var r="([a-zA-Z]|\\.[a-zA-Z.])[a-zA-Z0-9._]*";return{c:[e.HCM,{b:r,l:r,k:{keyword:"function if in break next repeat else for return switch while try tryCatch stop warning require library attach detach source setMethod setGeneric setGroupGeneric setClass c print ...",literal:"NULL NA TRUE FALSE T F Inf NaN NA_integer_|10 NA_real_|10 NA_character_|10 NA_complex_|10"},r:0},{cN:"number",b:"0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+[Li]?\\b",r:0},{cN:"number",b:"\\d+(?:[eE][+\\-]?\\d*)?L\\b",r:0},{cN:"number",b:"\\d+\\.(?!\\d)(?:i\\b)?",r:0},{cN:"number",b:"\\d+(?:\\.\\d*)?(?:[eE][+\\-]?\\d*)?i?\\b",r:0},{cN:"number",b:"\\.\\d+(?:[eE][+\\-]?\\d*)?i?\\b",r:0},{b:"`",e:"`",r:0},{cN:"string",c:[e.BE],v:[{b:'"',e:'"'},{b:"'",e:"'"}]},
{cN: "keyword", b: /(^|\s*)(:::?|\.)\w+(?=\(|$)/},
{cN: "meta",b: /(^|\s*)\w+(?=:::?|$)/,r: 0 }, ]}});

hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
```

```html
<html lang="en-us">
<head> <meta charset="utf-8"><link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.12.0/styles/agate.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
</head><body>

    <pre class="r"><code>library(officer)
doc_name &lt;-
    officer::read_docx() %&gt;% 
    flextable:::body_add_flextable(table_to_save) %&gt;% 
    print(target = &quot;word.docx&quot;)

.libPaths()
x = 4
c("a", "b")

package::function()$field
</code></pre>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highlightjs/cdn-release@9.12.0/build/highlight.min.js"></script>

</body></html>
```

Pretty close, but far from being perfect. The main hurdle here is that I struggle to fully understand how the parser interprets the patterns. Some of the results simply make no sense to me but [still work](https://i.pinimg.com/736x/ca/47/94/ca4794cfada458717c7aa99093a1f425.jpg).

Comment: I believe the suggested vanilla regex solution does not work because of [issues with lookaheads in highlight.js](https://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js/issues/1550). There is even an open [pull request](https://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js/pull/1349) that address this issue that never made it into the source.

Comment: PS: I would look into other js highlighters if this becomes a major obstacle. For instance, [rainbow.js](https://github.com/ccampbell/rainbow/blob/master/src/language/r.js) does a good job highlighting R and looks easier to adjust; setting colors is mostly a matter of identifying the detected style classes and set colors in the theme.css; [screenshot](https://ibb.co/iuh8jy).

Comment: It's a pity that `highlight.js` has problems with lookaheads. Nevertheless, @wp78de, your answer, and the comments were really helpful.